# Adding Characters to an Empty String in Python

Tags: python, string, uppercase, lowercase

I am attempting to have my program iterate over a user-inputted string and print it again, with a "u" in place of every uppercase letter, an "l" in place of every lowercase letter, and a "-" in place of any other character. This is what I have written:

```
txt = input()
modified_txt = ""

for char in txt:
    if char.isupper():
        modified_txt + "u"
    elif char.islower():
        modified_txt + "l"
    else:
        modified_txt + "-"

print(modified_txt)
```

For some reason, my output is a blank line, as though the variable "modified_txt" was never affected by the for loop. I'm sure there's a straightforward reason why this is the case but I'm at a loss.

Comment: `str`ings are immutable, meaning you can't modify them like this, you can tho use `+=` to reassign and add a character, so `modified_txt += "u"` and so on (it's equivalent to `modified_txt = modified_txt + "u"`)

Comment: Strings in python are unmutable, besides, need to reassign the variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maybe you need add `+` characters before `=`

```py
txt = input()
modified_txt = ""

for char in txt:
    if char.isupper():
        modified_txt += "u"
    elif char.islower():
        modified_txt += "l"
    else:
        modified_txt += "-"

print(modified_txt)
```

Comment: Didn't you mean " `=` characters after `+`"?

Answer (score 2):

A string is an immutable data type. So `+` is not an inplace operation for a string.

You need to reassign your variable with the new values. So change the lines:

```
modified_txt + SOMETHING
```

to

```
modified_txt = modified_txt + SOMETHING
```

or as `Matiiss` suggested to:

```
modified_txt += SOMETHING
```

Comment: I didn't exactly suggest it... it's just something that one should really use instead of that extended thing (which can be used to explain what `+=` does but not really used because, well, there's a shorter option that everyone uses)

Comment: @Matiiss I know people (such as myself) who prefer the first method. Because I think the first method is more readable. But you're absolutely right. One should know.

Comment: `+` shouldn't be in-place operation even for mutable types. That's what `+=` is for. `a + b` on its own in a line of code pretty much never makes sense.